# Making custom UI in swing

Tags: java, swing, graphics, custom-component, graphics2d

I need to make a custom ui which looks like the following image :-

[image]

I know how to change the button to that arrow shape and everything else.But I can't understand how to move those close ,restore and minimize buttons to the center and give them round shape (on Windows).

On Googling ,I found how to make custom shape windows but it doesn't meet my requirements.
Can anyone please tell me how to do this or any link.??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to create your own title bar as another panel with buttons and then remove the window decoration on the frame.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame(...);    
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//This will close the frame and exit
```

To minimize and maximize, listen for button events and use:

```
frame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);//minimizes

frame.setState(Frame.NORMAL);//restores
```

See [`Frame.setState(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setState%28int%29) for details.

Comment: :I think it will solve the problem .But what should i do to minimize and restore ,like ,for close i can use `System.exit(0);`.

Comment: Expanded answer for your enjoyment. Don't use System.exit(0).

Comment: :Using `setUndecorated(true)` disppears the close default button ,so what is the use of using `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`? You can't click on invisible thing !!!

Comment: That's a good point. You will need to make sure you've handled all error cases and report that as the integer in your System.exit(...).

Comment: @Naveen the point of still using setDefaultCloseOperation is it will effect how the method dispose works, which you can call from within in your code